# Using CSS to locate elements is causing issues with LocateAll

Tags: karate

I am using LocateAll to find instances of an element on the page. I am using CSS as the primary way to locate my elements due to them being faster than xpath.

The following is the html:

```
<tbody xpath="1"><tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            PhoneNumber
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Gender
        </th>
        <th>
            Nickname
        </th>
        <th>
            Shipping
        </th>
        <th>
            Closed
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to grab all instances of "th". I am using the following method:

```
* def headerCount = karate.sizeOf(locateAll('tbody tr th'))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js eval failed twice:document.querySelector("tbody tr th[2]")['textContent'], error: [type: MAP, value: {type=object, subtype=error, className=DOMException, description=DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'tbody tr th[2]' is not a valid selector.
```

I am assuming LocateAll works by indexing the locator to find all instances? If so, can I go an alternative route if possible (I'd rather not use xpath)?

Comment: no idea. maybe the html is malformed.